# Как отобразить картинку пользователя по его абсолютному пути?

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю выбор файла на вьюхе и кнопку отображения на экран:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <input id="file_image" type="file" name="uploadImage" />
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="sav_image()" class="sav">Save Image</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function sav_image() {
...
filepath = $('#file_image').attr('value');
...
$('#prev_image').attr('src', filepath)
}
```

Но в отображении на странице ничего нет, т.к. почему-то вместо абсолютного пути (C:\img\my_img.jpg) в `src` прописывается относительный (http://localhost/home/info/C:\img\my_img.jpg).

Собственно вопрос: как правильно отобразить картинку которую выбрал пользователь?

Comment: А причём тут C# и ASP.NET, пардон?

Comment: при том что все это выполняется во вьюхе контроллера.

Comment: _"все это выполняется во вьюхе контроллера"_ -- в вопросе: html и javascript. с сервера они передаются в браузер и javascript выполняется в браузере.

Comment: html и javascript. с сервера они передаются в браузер и javascript выполняется в браузере - не силен в терминологии, пусть будет по вашему. как отобразить правильно изображение то???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в браузере отобразить изображение, загруженное из файла на клиенте, надо добавить тег img в который выводится изображение.

```
<input id="file_image" type="file" />
<a href="#" onclick="preview()">Preview</a>
<img id="preview" style="max-width: 200px" />
```

и код для загрузки и показа изображения на странице

```
<script>
function preview() {
    var input = $('#file_image')[0];
    var f = input.files[0];
    if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function (e) { $("#preview").attr("src", fr.result); }
        fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
</script>
```