# Можно ли сделать такое в jquery?

Tags: jquery

Есть окно выбора картинки через input, можно ли сделать чтобы src картинки подгружалось при выборе из локального компьютера, или же может какое то хранилище для этого есть? Суть в том чтобы менять картинку без загрузки её на сервер

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделать можно. С помощью объекта [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Объект FileReader позволяет веб-приложениям асинхронно читать содержимое файлов (или буферы данных), хранящиеся на компьютере пользователя, используя объекты File или Blob, с помощью которых задается файл или данные для чтения.

Его метод `.readAsDataURL()` позволит считать данные файла в виде [data: URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL), которые мы потом кладем в атрибут src картинки, и она отобразится.

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="file" id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

--

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e){
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

Comment: было бы неплохо пояснить что именно делает приведенный код

Comment: перед загрузкой надо добавить проверку типа файла, чтобы был 'image.*'. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480686/196972).